# Vanilla Compact and Repair vs DBEngine.CompactDatabase in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have been running a data load process over the last couple of days and periodically running compact & repair over a 2 GB database from the menu. As I was getting a little tired of stopping and starting I wrote some VBA to do this. After running DBEngine.CompactDatabase I have found that the file has compacted quite a lot more than before (1.3 GB vs 2 GB). It's an accdb database with a single large table, nothing fancy.
Should I be worried or should I be running DBEngine.CompactDatabase on these large files as standard.

Comment: You *should* be concerned, but not so much about the differences between the two ways of compacting. If you are running close to the 2 GB limit in the day-to-day operation of the database then you are running the risk of exceeding that limit and experiencing a crash, possibly losing data in the process. You should either find a way to *significantly* reduce the size of the Access database or consider moving the data to another back-end like SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Gord but it's actually a database that is used for loading data prior to upload to sql-server. It's not for day to day use